# Progress bar in asp.net core with vuejs(excel upload with controller)

Tags: vue.js, asp.net-core

private async Task BulkProcessAsync(Command command)
{

```
  foreach (var item in command.ExcelFile)
 {
  //code
 }
```

}

```
                        <input type="file" id="customFile"
                               :class="['form-control-file','custom-file-input']" :accept="sheetJSFT" @change="_change">
                        Choose the excel file
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I need a progress bar for the file upload in asp.net core and vuejs. I have shared controller code and vuejs upload part. Any assistance will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: stackoverflow is for specific debugging help.  you've not specified an actual problem.  "I need a progress bar" sounds more like a request for someone to write code for you.  If you've tried to code your own progress bar, what issues have you run into?  what errors are you trying to solve?  what is wrong with your current code? please include this information in your question and review [how do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)